# How to update the title and body of a facebook ad via the API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I want to use the facebook API v2.5 to update the title and body of an existing facebook ad. I am using the PHP sdk (and the facebook API explorer). What is the correct way to do this? This what I have tried so far.

After fetching the ad, I read the related ad_creative:

```
$ad = new Ad(<ad_id>);
$ad_creatives = $ad->getAdCreatives();

$creative = new AdCreative($ad_creatives[0]->id);

// fetch from API 
$fields = $creative->getFields();
$creative->read($fields);
```

Changing a value and calling update has no effect:

```
$creative->{AdCreativeFields::BODY} = 'When life gives you lemons';
$creative->update();
```

Another possible way is to create a new creative and clone the data from the existing one:

```
$data = $creative->getData();

$new_creative = new AdCreative(null, <act_id>);
$new_creative->setData($data);
$new_creative->create();
```

But it seems I will need to do some tinkering to get it right, because the api is returning errors. 
Btw, the app has the following permissions: ads_management, manage_pages, publish_pages.

Comment: Try the examples here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup#Updating

Answer (score 1):

Creative content is immutable.
In order to update the tittle or body you will need to create a new creative (and then update your ad to use the new creative instead of the old one).